# Is there an equivalent to content_css for JS in TinyMCE 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

Is there an equivalent to **content_css** when initializing TinyMCE 4 to include a **javascript file** ?

Same as :

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    content_css: ['path/to/css/file.css'],
    ...
});
```

Or any other way to do so ?

Expected final use would be to : Add tabs and allow user to click on tab titles to edit content of each tab